# pyqt5でQListViewで表示させる項目を変化させたい

Tags: python3, pyqt5

pyqt5でQListViewを使ったときに表示されるリストを後から変更したいです。次は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)
        self.nodes = ['node0', 'node1', 'node2', "node4", "node5"]

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        return self.createIndex(row, column, self.nodes[row])

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.internalPointer() in self.nodes:
            return 0
        return len(self.nodes)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == 0: 
            return index.internalPointer()
        else:
            return None

    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction         

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled        

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['text/xml']

    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimedata.setData('text/xml', 'mimeData')
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        print ('dropMimeData %s %s %s %s' % (data.data('text/xml'), action, row, parent))
        return True


class MainForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.treeModel = TreeModel()

        self.view2 = QListView()
        self.view2.setModel(self.treeModel)
        self.view2.activated.connect(self.viewClicked2)#ダブルクリックでの動作
        self.view2.clicked.connect(self.viewClicked)

        self.btn=QPushButton("data")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_data)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view2)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def viewClicked(self, indexClicked):
        print('index of proxy row', indexClicked.row())

    def viewClicked2(self, index):
        print(index.row())

    def change_data(self):
        self.treeModel.nodes=["data1","data2","data3"]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

これを実行することで、次のようなGUIが作成されます。
[image: 画像]
ここで、右のdataボタンを押したときに左のリストに表示されるデータが[data1,data2,data3]に変更されるように書いてみたつもりなのですが、ボタンを押すと、次のようなエラーが延々と表示されます。

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/toma/Desktop/pyqt/アイテムモデル/practice2.py", line 20, in index
    return self.createIndex(row, column, self.nodes[row])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

しかし、どのように修正すればよいのか全く分かりません。どなたかご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

修正前

```
class MainForm(QWidget):
    def change_data(self):
        self.treeModel.nodes=["data1","data2","data3"]
```

修正後

```
class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def changeNodes(self, nodes):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.endResetModel()

class MainForm(QWidget):
    def change_data(self):
        self.treeModel.changeNodes(["data1","data2","data3"])
```

QAbstractItemModelとQListViewのような、モデル・ビューアの関連性を持つものは、単にモデルの方で内容を更新してもダメで、「モデルの内容が変わった」という事をビューアに知らせなければなりません。
QAbstractItemModelの場合、[begin/endで始まるメソッド](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#protected-functions)がそれだと思っています。
(「思っています」というのは、明確なソースを見つけられなかったから。ただ自分の経験上、このような仕組みのものは大抵そのようになっています)
ですので、内容の更新をする場合には、更新の内容に従って然るべきメソッドを呼んでください。
(今回は内容の全とっかえのようですので、「beginResetModel/endResetModel」でよろしいかと。)

ちなみに、わざわざTreeModelのメソッドchangeNodesを作ったのは、Qt5のQAbstractItemModelクラスのbeginResetModel/endResetModelメソッドがprotectedメンバだから。
まぁpythonにpublic/protectedなんて制約はないのでこんなことをしなくてもいいかもしれませんが、なんとなくです。

Comment: 回答、及び詳しい解説ありがとうございます！おかげ様で正常に動作させることが出来ました。